# Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK

Tags: node.js, sdk, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Is it possible to develop the node SDK part of a Hyperledger Fabric project with a microservice Nodejs project or with a simple Nodejs project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to at least start the development of a Node.js project as something that can run from the command line line. Fixing errors and viewing log output will be easier. I presume that for a microservice, you will run it as a docker container which will listen on some port for activity. All of this can be done first as a standalone Node.js project. Once developed and tested, just create the docker image and then run it.